# Alternative to KILL 'SID' on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

If I submit a series of SQL statements (each with GO in *sqlcmd*) that I want to make an reasonable attempt to run on an Azure SQL Data Warehouse, I've found in sqlcmd how to ignore errors.  But I've seen if I want to abort a statement in that sequence of statements with:

```
KILL "SIDxxxxxxx";
```

The whole session ends:

```
 Msg 111202, Level 16, State 1, Server adws_database, Line 1
 111202;Query QIDyyyyyyyyyy has been cancelled.
```

Is there a way to not end a query session in Azure SQL Data Warehouse? Similar to how postgres's 
     pg_cancel_backend() 
works?

In postgres the

```
pg_terminate_backed(<pid>)
```

seems to be working similarly to the ADW

```
KILL 'SIDxxxx'
```

command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a client can cancel a running request without aborting the whole session.  In SSMS this is what the red square does during query execution.

Sqlcmd doesn't expose any way to cancel a running request, though.  Other client interfaces do, like the .NET SqlClient you can use SqlCommand.Cancel()

David

Comment: I filed an enhancement request - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/17890948-cancel-query-in-sqlcmd